# Printing Press Recordings.

Tags: field-recording, sfx, library

Hey Guys,
So recently visited the [Black Stone Press](http://www.blackstonepress.ca/Black_Stone_Press/Home.html) in Granville Island, Vancouver. [Here](https://soundcloud.com/thesoundguy-2/sets/printing-press) are some of the sounds from that day. I would like to know what you think about them. 
Thank you.

Comment: Really cool stuff!

Comment: Those sound cool, what are your plans for them?

Comment: As of now, just building my own library. Trying to get as many different sounds as possible.

Comment: Very nice! What did you use to record?

Answer (score 3):

Really nice work!  [I recorded some printing presses last year](http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2012/01/recordings-of-cd-press-and-printing.html), and found the big industrial ones to be incredibly challenging to get just right.  I was really running and gunning in a massive industrial complex though.  Sounds like you had the opportunity to sit and do a study on one machine, which is very cool IMO.

What was your recording setup?

Comment: hey thank you @Rene. Glad you liked them. I'm a big fan of your work too. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Rene Yes, I did have the opportunity to study the [Heidelberg printing press](http://attheacademy.org/files/heidelberg.jpg) before I could record. The owner of the press was very kind enough to let me and a friend come over to their facility and record for a couple of hours. We took multiple takes of the machines. I used the [Cold Gold](http://contactmicrophones.com/products-sscmmed.html) large suction cup contact mic, Sennheiser ME66 and Sound Devices 722 and recorded different perspectives of the press and then combined them together.